# Unity broken after changing few compiz settings, fresh 11.10 install

Tags: unity, 11.10, compiz

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unity just disappears after changing launcher icon size and won't come back](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66737/unityjust-disappears-after-changing-launcher-icon-size-and-wont-come-back)

I just did a fresh install of Ubuntu 11.10 and then changed (or tried to anyway) some settings of the unity launcher using the compizconfig settings manager. I only changed some settings in the unity plugin and some in the alt-tab switcher thingie I think. Then when I closed the ccsm it crashed and my unity bar is gone and won't return even after several reboots, unity --replace, unity --reset and even reinstalling everything unity-related. When I try to start unity in the terminal this is the output I get:

```
unity --reset
unity-panel-service: no process found
Checking if settings need to be migrated ...no
Checking if internal files need to be migrated ...no
Backend     : gconf
Integration : true
Profile     : default
Adding plugins
Skipping upgrade com.canonical.unity.unity.01.upgrade
Skipping upgrade com.canonical.unity.unity.02.upgrade
Initializing core options...done
Initializing bailer options...done
Initializing detection options...done
Initializing composite options...done
Initializing opengl options...done
Initializing decor options...done
Initializing mousepoll options...done
Initializing vpswitch options...done
Initializing animation options...done
Initializing snap options...done
compiz (expo) - Warn: failed to bind image to texture
Initializing expo options...done
Initializing move options...done
Initializing place options...done
Initializing grid options...done
Initializing gnomecompat options...done
Initializing wall options...done
Initializing ezoom options...done
Initializing workarounds options...done
Initializing staticswitcher options...[ERROR]: Option "next_button" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "next_key" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "prev_button" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "prev_key" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "next_all_button" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "next_all_key" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "prev_all_button" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "prev_all_key" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "next_group_button" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "next_group_key" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "prev_group_button" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "prev_group_key" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "next_no_popup_button" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "next_no_popup_key" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "prev_no_popup_button" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "prev_no_popup_key" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "next_panel_button" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "next_panel_key" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "prev_panel_button" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "prev_panel_key" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "speed" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "timestep" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "window_match" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "minimized" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "auto_change_vp" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "popup_delay" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "mouse_select" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "saturation" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "brightness" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "opacity" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "icon" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "icon_only" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "mipmap" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "row_align" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "focus_on_switch" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "bring_to_front" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "highlight_mode" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "highlight_rect_hidden" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "highlight_color" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "highlight_border_color" already defined
[ERROR]: Option "highlight_border_inlay_color" already defined
done
Initializing resize options...done
Initializing fade options...done
Initializing scale options...done
Initializing session options...done
```

Any thoughts on how to fix this? I also installed the proprietary nvidia drivers (current version that was recommended) and then rebooted without a problem, only after changing some things using the ccsm it crashed so I don't think this is the problem?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This question should instead be filed as a bug report, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).