# Unity just disappears after changing launcher icon size and won't come back

Tags: unity, 11.10, compiz

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)

**What I did:**

In a fresh setup of 11.10, I used `compizconfig-settings-manager` as [explained in this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29553/how-can-i-configure-unity/62903#62903) to change the icon size of the Unity launcher.

**What happened:**

As soon as I did this, the application froze and the launcher disappeared. I thought, well, maybe Unity crashed, so I logged out with <kbd>Ctrl-Alt-Del</kbd>, and logged in again.

Unity still does not appear anymore. I am just left with my desktop background and Nautilus running. I can open a new Nautilus window, and browse my file system, but that's about it.

**What works:**

I *can* log into Unity 2D, only the "normal" Unity does not work.

So, how do I get Unity back? Is there any way to reset the configuration, or look for some more detailed error messages?

---

**What I already tried:**

- Starting a Terminal and running `unity --reset`. It's stuck at "Initializing session options … done", and nothing else happens.
- Starting a Terminal and running `unity --replace`. Same as above.
- From the 2D mode, calling `unity --replace` or `-- reset`. It hangs after "Starting unity-window-decorator", and if I abort the process, my keyboard input is disabled.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm pretty sure I had the same problem as you.

What I did to fix it was open a Terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>), type [`ccsm`](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/compizconfig-settings-manager) in the Terminal and then enabled the Ubuntu Unity plugin and it now works again.

- Warning: [What are some of the issues with CCSM and why would I want to avoid it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80589/what-are-some-of-the-issues-with-ccsm-and-why-should-i-not-use-it)

Comment: This is exactly it. It gave me a message about resolving conflicts, but I ignored and skipped it. Seems to work for now!

Comment: Talk about conflicts. There are about 7 key bindings that conflict with unity's settings.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but none of the solutions explained here works.

Here is how I solved my Unity launcher problem:

- Open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- Open the `compizconfig-settings-manager` with this command : `ccsm`
  (if it's not installed, use `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`)
- Click on the category: Desktop
- Marked Ubuntu Unity Plugin and answer to all the conflict key you may have
- Unity Launcher is back!

Comment: *> none of the solutions explained here works* – yes, of course. The one I marked as accepted. Type `ccsm` in the terminal and tick the Ubuntu Unity Plugin. Also, please check your formatting, `<pre>` is only used for code.

Answer (score 0):

Try running `unity --reset` from a terminal.

Comment: I can do this in Unity 2D terminal, but that doesn't help. I went to `/usr/bin/X11/xterm` and entered the above command, but it's stuck at `Initializing session options … done`.

Comment: That's strange... Output of `/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p`?

Comment: All positive...

Answer (score 0):

Try running unity --reset (or unity --replace or both) from the 2D environment and restart the computer afterwards. I've had the same problem and it worked for me.

Comment: No luck either. It hangs at "starting unity-window-decorator", and if I abort the process then, my keyboard stops working, and nothing is really fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem..

I logged in to the Gnome shell 
ran the compiz Configuration utility and found out that the unity component was disabled 
( of course I did not do it ) but I re-enabled it , solved a few conflicts and rebooted
I logged in to Unity and every thing worked fine